# Integral and periodic function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, periodic-functions

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ be $2\pi$-periodic function. For all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we consider the interval $I_a=[a-\pi, a+\pi]$. If $f\in L^1(I_0)$, then $$\int_{I_0}f\;d\lambda=\int_{I_a}\;f\;d\lambda,$$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I know the this result follows from the fact that the function $f$ is $2\pi$- periodic and traslation invariance of Lebesgue measure, but I don't know how to prove it explicitly.

Could anyone give me a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: When in doubt, always prove it for simple functions first. Then for non-negative measurable functions (using monotone convergence). Then for arbitrary $L^1$ functions. This is in fact how the proof of the general change of measure theorem works anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $I_a$ as the (disjoint) union $[a - \pi, (2k+1)\pi]\cup [(2k+1)\pi, a + \pi]$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. Can you now separately "shift" these two parts onto (disjoint) subsets of $I_0$ using the periodicity of $f$?